# Module representing rational numbers

Tags: beginner, haskell, modules, rational-numbers

Taking inspiration from [SICP Exercise 2.1](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html#%_thm_2.1), I decided to implement a module in Haskell for rational numbers.

Some of my concerns include:

- Is this idiomatic Haskell?
- Besides `Num`, `Eq`, `Ord`, `Show`, and `Read`, are there other typeclasses I should be implementing?  I've got "free-floating" functions `toInteger'` and `rationalDiv`.  Is there some typeclass that would accommodate them?
- Is this a good way to handle division by zero?
- How is the code layout and organization?

```hs
module Rational'
( toInteger'
, rationalDiv
) where

data Rational' = Rational' { numer :: Integer
                           , denom :: Integer
                           }

instance Num Rational' where
  (+)           = rationalAdd
  (-)           = rationalSub
  (*)           = rationalMul
  abs           = rationalAbs
  signum        = rationalSignum
  fromInteger   = rationalFromInteger

instance Eq Rational' where
  (==)          = rationalEq

instance Ord Rational' where
  compare       = rationalCompare

instance Show Rational' where
  show          = rationalShow

instance Read Rational' where
  readsPrec     = rationalRead



divByZero n = error ("Division by zero: " ++ (show n) ++ "/0")

rationalAdd :: Rational' -> Rational' -> Rational'
a `rationalAdd` b = reduce $ Rational' (an * bd + bn * ad) (ad * bd)
  where (Rational' an ad) = a
        (Rational' bn bd) = b

rationalSub :: Rational' -> Rational' -> Rational'
a `rationalSub` b = a + (Rational' (-bn) bd)
  where bn = numer b
        bd = denom b

rationalMul :: Rational' -> Rational' -> Rational'
a `rationalMul` b = reduce $ Rational' (an * bn) (ad * bd)
  where (Rational' an ad) = a
        (Rational' bn bd) = b

rationalDiv :: Rational' -> Rational' -> Rational'
a `rationalDiv` b = a * (Rational' bd bn)
  where bn = numer b
        bd = denom b

rationalAbs :: Rational' -> Rational'
rationalAbs (Rational' n d) = reduce $ Rational' (abs n) (abs d)

{- You might expect the result of signum to be an Int (namely -1 | 0 | 1), but
 - the Num typeclass requires it to be the same type as the input. -}
rationalSignum :: Rational' -> Rational'
rationalSignum (Rational' n d)
  | n == 0              = 0
  | (n > 0) == (d > 0)  = 1
  | otherwise           = Rational' (-1) 1

rationalFromInteger :: Integer -> Rational'
rationalFromInteger n = Rational' n 1

{- Truncates towards 0 -}
toInteger' :: Rational' -> Integer
toInteger' (Rational' n d) = n `div` d

rationalEq :: Rational' -> Rational' -> Bool
a `rationalEq` b = (a `rationalCompare` b) == EQ

rationalCompare :: Rational' -> Rational' -> Ordering
a `rationalCompare` b
  | (ad == 0)                   = divByZero a
  | (bd == 0)                   = divByZero b
  | (signum ad) == (signum bd)  = (an * bd) `compare` (bn * ad)
  | otherwise                   = (bn * ad) `compare` (an * bd)
  where (Rational' an ad) = a
        (Rational' bn bd) = b

rationalShow :: Rational' -> [Char]
rationalShow a = (show $ numer a) ++ "/" ++ (show $ denom a)

rationalRead :: Int -> [Char] -> [(Rational', [Char])]
rationalRead _ r = [(Rational' (read ns) (read ds), "")]
  where (ns, (_:ds)) = break (=='/') r

reduce :: Rational' -> Rational'
reduce a = Rational' (n `div` common) (d' `div` common)
  where (Rational' n d) = a
        d'
          | (d == 0)    = divByZero n
          | otherwise   = d
        common = (gcd n d') * (signum d')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too bad.

1. You do not export Rational' from the module so no outside code can make one directly
2. `numer` and `denom` will conflict with a similar function name in any other code which imports your module. Perhaps `rational'Numer` and `rational'Denom`?
3. See http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html for a good intro to numbers in Haskell. You missed the `Fractional` class which defines `div`, `recip`, and `fromRational`.
4. Why are `rationalSub` and `rationalDiv` not defined like add and mult? Be consistent.
5. In `rationalSignum` your comment says the reader would expect a 0 or 1 Int but the return needs to be of the `Rational'` type and then you actually return 0 or 1. Be consistent and return `Rational' 0 1` and `Rational' 1 1`
6. `rationalFromInteger` could be `rationalFromInteger = (flip Rational') 1`
7. I would define `reduce` like this

   ```
   reduce (Rational' n 0) = divByZero n
   reduce (Rational' n d) = Rational' (n `div` common) (d `div` common)
     where common = (gcd n d) * (signum d)
   ```